# Fetching objects form core data by IndexPath

Tags: core-data, swift4

I have a `TableView`. By tapping an entry in this table, another view opens in which that entry is editable.

What's the proper way to handle this? I am aware that I can fetch entries from Core Data via predicates like this:

```
func fetchEntriesStartingWith(startingDate:Date) -> [FuelEntry] {

    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "FuelEntry")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", startingDate as CVarArg)

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(FuelEntry.date), ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
        return try (CoreDataHandler.managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [FuelEntry] ?? [FuelEntry]())
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return []
    }
}
```

However, this seems error prone: What if I have two entries with the exact same values (might happen in my application) and thus, the `NSFetchRequest` returns two entries?

Obviously, those two entries will have different IDs, but I'm unsure how to work with those and infer which entry will correspond to what `indexPath`.

Comment: Don't fetch. Get the item at index (path) from the data source array. By the way you can get rid of this cumbersome syntax `as? [FuelEntry] ?? [FuelEntry]())` with a specific fetch request `let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<FuelEntry>(entityName: "FuelEntry")`

Comment: @vadian Thank you, I should have thought of this.